# on input element fire change event only once after specific time period

Tags: jquery

I would like to make input change fire only once after specific time period.

in below code suppose i input 3 character it alert three time after 1500 millisecond.

I would like to alert only once.

Here is my js code.

```
jQuery("#width").on('input',function(){
setTimeout(function(){
           alert('hello');
     },1500)
```

});

[JSFIDDEL](https://jsfiddle.net/vs4k2vhh/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need debounce function. Either use lodash [_.debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce) or write your own simple one. Then use it like this:

```
jQuery("#width").on('input', debounce(function() {
  alert('hello')
}, 1500))
```

simple debounce function could look something like this:

```
function debounce(callback, delay) {
  var timeout
  return function() {
    var args = arguments
    clearTimeout(timeout)
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      callback.apply(this, args)
    }.bind(this), delay)
  }
}
```

Here is a demo:

```js
jQuery("#width").on('input', debounce(function() {
  alert('hello');
}, 1500));

function debounce(callback, delay) {
  var timeout
  return function() {
    var args = arguments
    clearTimeout(timeout)
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      callback.apply(this, args)
    }.bind(this), delay)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="width" />
```